# HTML/CSS Div(height: 80px) over Div(height:100%;)

Tags: css, html, height

i try to get my Homepage-Layout to work.

Now the height of the div "list" should be 80px smaller from bottom.
I made some tests with margin and position: absolute but I couldn't get it.

```
#body, #left, #map, #list {
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  float:left; 
  width:270px;
}

#head {
  height:80px; 
  background-color:blue;
}

#list {
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:green;
}

#map {
  background-color:red;
}

<body >
  <div id="left">
    <div id="head"> </div>  
    <div id="list"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"> </div>
</body>
```

this is how it should look like:

```
     280px      100%
     ______________________
80px|head |map             |
    |_____|                |
    |list |                |
    |     |                |
    |     |                |
100%|     |                |
    |_____|________________|
```

this is how it looks like now:

```
     280px      100%
     ______________________
80px|head |map             |
    |_____|                |
    |list |                |
    |     |                |
    |     |                |
100%|     |                |
    |     |________________|
    |     |
    |_____|
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need more description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: The #list is scrollable if the content gets to long. But the height of #list should be bound by the height of its parent (#left)

Comment: Just to clarify; head is the top 80px of the page, map is the bottom 80px of the page, and list expands to the rest?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not specifying a height at all for your div (except `#head`).

If you want list to have a height, you have the choice to specify a direct height to `#left` or to `#list`.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RAcPV/) for an example with the `#left` height set to something (and not 100%).

Comment: Of course i want the height being dynamic for resizing the Browser.

Comment: In this case, the error (i think) comes just from the fact that you shouldn't use `#body` but rather `body` without the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

So now (since your answer) I understand your problem.

To solve it, the following is needed:

- add `position:absolute` to `#head`
- add `width:100%;` to `#head`
- add `position:relative` to `#left`

Explanation:

The position absolute will put `#head` in the top left corner of his closest parent.
It's width will default to 0. So we need to put it to 100% to take all the parent width.
However the reference for an absolute positioned div is the closest parent that has a position that is either `absolute` or `relative` (or the body if nothing matches).
So we set the position of `#left` to `relative` in order to have it has a reference for `#head`. No `absolute` because we don't want it to be crushed by map

Other solution:

- add `overflow-y:hidden;` to `#left`

This way, everything that overflows from `#left` on a vertical axis, won't be displayed.

You can choose the solution that fits your need.
One (the overflow one) will have the bottom cut. On the other, the top will be cut (or you'll need to add some `padding-top` to avoid that)

Hope that helps.